# How to setup the enviroment that bluepy can scan without sudo?

Tags: python, linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I wrote some Python3 script, that scans for devices. If they match a "name" I am connecting to them and do some ble stuff. The script is build on top of the `bluepy` module.

One think I don't like, is that I need to run the device scanning as `sudo`(like `sudo python3 getDev.py`). Any ideas how to make a user being able to scan without root rights?

Guess I need to add the local user to a group etc. Any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On linux Bluetooth protocol stack need special privileges to interact with.

These privileges are implemented through properties called capabilities, see [man 7 capability](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) for details.

The tool to assign capabilities is the program `setcap`.

In case of bluepy it is the binary `bluepy-helper` that interact with the bluetooth protocol stack, so locate where it is installed the package bluepy and run:

```
sudo setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_admin+eip' ${PY_SITE_PACKAGES_DIR}/bluepy/bluepy-helper
```

See also [here](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/313)

Comment: Any ideas how to do that on Android, when using buildozer to build an kivy app?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60319920/porting-a-python3-app-from-linux-to-android-using-kivy-and-bluepy